# Use a Timer to change value periodically

Tags: c#, timer

Hye there I am new to C# and just want to run a timer manually! So i just want to know what I am doing wrong in my code. I just need to display a simple message inside my timer! my code is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Timers.Timer time;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        time = new System.Timers.Timer();
        time.Interval = 10;
        time.Enabled = true;
        time.Start();
    }

    private void time_Tick(object e, EventArgs ea)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if i am doing something wrong Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't edit the question so that correct answers no longer apply to the question. Mark answer as correct if the original question was answered correctly, then create a new question or ask followup questions in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to listen to the `Elapsed` event. Add:

```
time.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(time_Tick);
```

To the initialisation of the timer and it should call the callback function when the timer have elapsed (at the moment 10ms)

Note also that the callback function will be called *every* 10 ms.
Add `time.Stop();` inside the callback function if you wish it to stop run.

Comment: And the `time.Enabled = true;` call is not needed, calling `time.Start();` will start and enable the timer itself.

Comment: though i used your answer but it is pausing and showing the output at once

Comment: Yes, you set the interval to 10, which is 10 milliseconds. If you wish it to be 10 seconds, thats 10000 in interval instead.

Comment: see my edit i want to show the value of for loop every after 1000 intervals but its showing me all values just after the whole interval

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do there, but I'd say that would be better as another question, cause its not really relevant to the original question, if I don't totally misunderstand it. :)

Comment: i just want to add a pause in the for loop! like in java i can use sleep method to add some pause

Comment: You can use sleep in c# too, but i would not recommend it in this case. The timer is called every 10ms (milliseconds), and will then do whatever is defined in the callback function.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:**

Maybe it is better to use class `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead of `System.Timers.Timer`. There you can call your function and also access your Textbox.

Otherwise you will receive an InvalidOperationException by trying to access your Textbox `txt` in `time_Tick`.

You don't neet a loop for incrementing your value `i`. just restart your timer and set the new value. What you are doing now is waiting **ONE** tick (lasting 1000 ms) and then starting your loop.

For example this could be your method:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    private int i = 0;
    private Timer time;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        time = new Timer();
        time.Tick += time_Tick;
        time.Interval = 1000;
        time.Start();
    }

    private void time_Tick(object e, EventArgs ea)
    {
        if (i < 100)
        {
            txt.Text = i.ToString();
            i++;
            time.Start();
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: which errors? have you replaced your usings like i mentioned?

Comment: it shows me the out put without any pause what i want is to just show the output of for loop every after 1000 interval like i=1 then pause i=2 then pause and so on! Like in Java i can use sleep method

Comment: System.Timer Does not contain a definition for 'Tick' and no extenion method 'Tick' for accepting a first argument of type System.Timer Could be found...

Comment: Tick is part of the System.Windows.Forms.Timer namespace, not System.Timers, check first lines of the answer for info about that.